# ¿Cómo liberar memoria de una vista que se ha llamado desde otra vista?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo un programa con una vista que muestra otra vista encima de la siguiente manera:

```
self.secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview: self.secondView.view];
```

Una vez que he usado la segunda vista, la borro de la vista que la llama con:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview]
```

Ahora solo me queda liberar la memoria que ocupa esta segunda vista. Mis dudas son estas:
¿Se puede liberar la memoria de esta vista dentro de un método de la misma vista o hay que hacerlo desde un método de la vista que la ha llamado? ¿Cómo se haría?

Comment: una vez que la elimines de la superview, self.secondView = nil

Comment: Para mostrar una nueva vista encima de otra al pulsar un botón no debería haber usado un presentViewController ? Que otras opciones tengo?

Answer (score 1):

`removeFromSuperview` liberará la memoria si la gestión de memoria no encuentra ningún problema.

Aún así puedes asegurarte igualándola a `nil`:

```
self.secondView = nil;
```

Comment: Cuando quito la segunda vista (secondView) de la vista padre con removeFromSuperView no me libera la memoria, ya que en la vista padre self.secondView tiene un valor distinto a nil. Lo que tengo puesto es que sino me borra la memoria y vuelvo a agregar esta vista a la vista padre con addSubview no me haga el "alloc init" de nuevo para que me reserve mas memoria. No se si esto lo estoy haciendo bien o es añadir mas código innecesario.

Comment: ¿Le has pasado el Instruments? ¿Has dejado un periodo de tiempo razonable para que el recolector de basura haga su cometido?

Comment: Dejar un periodo razonable para el recolector de basura no seria  una buena solución en mi caso ya que  muestra la segunda vista según un botón que pulsa el usuario. Entonces lo que hago ahora es cuando el usuario pulsa el botón antes de hacer un "alloc init" lo igualo a nil. Pero aun así puede que no sea optimo pues igualo el puntero a nil pero sigue habiendo una memoria reservada de la anterior vez. El instruments no lo he usado nunca ¿ Esta en el simulador ?

Comment: Si haces clic y mantienes pulsado en el botón de "play" de Xcode, te aparecerá un menú en el que podrás elegir una opción que reza "Profile". Esto arrancará tu aplicación y mandará el PID a Instruments para que puedas analizar cómo se comporta tu aplicación a nivel de consumo de recursos. Elige qué quieres monitorizar (en tu caso los leaks de memoria) y observa cómo se comporta tu aplicación en el tiempo; haz pruebas, muestra la ventana y ciérrala varias veces a ver si de verdad tienes una fuga.

Comment: Con Instruments observo en "Category - All Heap & Anonymous VM" que: Si igualo la vista a "nil" y vuelvo a hacer un "alloc init" a la que voy agregando y removiendo la vista los Mbytes de columna "Persistent Bytes" va creciendo y  barra azul clara  "Transient/Total Bytes" también. Pero si no igualo a "nil" y controlo con un "if" que  me haga un "alloc init" en caso que secondView ya sea "nil" el "Persistent Bytes" no crece y la barra azul clara del "Transient/Total Bytes" tampoco.¿Significa esto que si opto por igualar a nil debería hacer  "dealloc" para liberar memoria ocupada por vista?

Comment: Teóricamente igualando a `nil`, el recolector acabará por liberar la memoria... Si quieres optimizar, creo que lo razonable es reutilizar la vista (en caso de que siempre sea la misma) o, como bien dices, probar a hacer un `dealloc`...

Answer (score 1):

Depende de qué estes haciendo con esa segunda vista. Si la has creado desde la primera y una vez que la has instanciado no la destruyes y solo la pones y la quitas cuando necesitas usando el addSubview y el removeFromSuperview, la única forma de liberar memoria de esa secondView es mediante una llamada a un método y ese método eliminara dentro de esa vista lo que pueda eliminar. Cuando lo necesites hace un

```
[self.secondView.cleanMemory];
```

o como le quieras llamar y ese método tendrá que saber que elimina. La self.secondView siempre seguirá existiendo, no tendras que volver a instanciarla para mostrarla.

Si por el contrario, cuando la elimines haciendo el [self.secondView removeFromSuperview]; y luego te aseguras con un self.secondSuperview = nil, entonces la segunda vista se destruye y libera toda la memoria. Si quieres volver a mostrarla tienes que volver a instanciarla

Comment: En mi caso quiero que una vez que haga un removeFromSuperView y un nil, también me libere la memoria donde apuntaba el secondView. Porque no se si estaré haciendo algo mal ya que con removeFromSuperView y nil, la memoria sigue ocupada. ¿ El secondView lo tengo en una property declarado como "strong" y "nonatomic" puede ser por esto que no me libere la memoria de la secondView ?

Comment: Pero tu en secondview, que has usado? elementos propios de cocoa, como labels, buttons, etc? o te has montado un árbol binario con punteros? Si es lo segundo, tienes que ocuparte tu de deshacerlo y liberar. Si son elementos de cocoa al ponerlo a nil se libera solo

Comment: He usado elementos de cocoa pero lo que me extraña es que cuando hago nil y vuelvo a hacer el "alloc init" si pongo el instruments y voy cambiando vistas varias veces como comentaba mas arriba me va subiendo la memoria consumida y si no hago nil  pero aprovecho el alloc init de la clase ya instanciada anteriormente me vuelve a aparecer la vista sin ningún problema. He leído que dependiendo de como declare las propertys si hago un nil del objeto instanciado y no hay ningún puntero mas apuntando a la memoria ocupada en la vista entonces es cuando se libera la memoria.

Comment: Estas usando delegates? o estas referenciando a otra clase? si es asi le pondrás weak delante? de todas formas la memoria que se usa en el simulador no es del todo una prueba fiable. Enchufale un teléfono y el instruments sobre el telefono

Comment: dentro de la vista que quiero liberar la memoria hay un delegate de tableView. La vista la declaro con un property strong nonatomic.

Comment: Pues debería liberar sin problemas. Prueba si puedes con un teléfono y pon el código de  secundaryViewcontroller si no es muy largo

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando ARC?

Me parece que el problema pasa porque el secondView que tenes declarado es  **STRONG** en lugar de **WEAK**. Por que debería ser WEAK? Porque ante la siguiente línea de código:

```
[self.view addSubview: self.secondView.view];
```

self.view tiene la referencia **STRONG** de secondView y estas teniendo 2 referencias **STRONG** al mismo objeto; por tal motivo los IBOutlets son weak en general excepto las constraints que quieras desactivar. Proba con el siguiente fragmento, no lo verifique pero creo debería funcionar:

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; 
self.secondView = secondView 
[self.view addSubview: secondView.view];
```

y en la declaración de secondView donde dice **STRONG** tenes que reemplazarlo por **WEAK**.

Comment: Lo he probado, sii lo declaro como WEAK al cerrar la vista con [self.view removeFromSuperview] no me la cierra mientras que con STRONG si.

Comment: pero deberia ser  [self.secondView removeFromSuperview], sino estarias queriendo remover la vista principal

Comment: Le pongo un self.view porque remuevo la vista dentro de un método del mismo secondView no lo hago desde la vista que llama a secondView

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el post se complicó con las referencias a `self.view` que en realidad eran referencias a la view de la secondView(que es un view controller).

Aun así, me suena raro el tema de que estas metiendo la vista de un viewController adentro de otra view. Por ahí nos podes explicar un poco mas de esto.

Ya que normalmente los childViewControllers (view controllers hijos son los que están embebidos en otros view controllers) se manejan de otra forma.

1. Llamar al  método `addChildViewController:` en el view controller contenedor(o padre)
2. Este método le dice a UIKit que tu view controller contenedor esta ahora manejando la vista del view controller hijo .
3. Se hace el `addSubView:` agregando la vista del view controller hijo a la vista del view controller contenedor.  (Recordar configurar el tamaño y la posición de la vista del view controller hijo como parte de este proceso)
4. Agregar cualquier contraint necesaria
5. Llamar al metodo `didMoveToParentViewController:` en el view controller hijo

Ahora volviendo a tu problemática inicial si `SecondViewController` fuera una `UIView` y no tuvieras la indirección de `self.secondView.view` la solución de @badarock seria la correcta. Al ser la `secondView` weak y estar retenida por la view del view controller contenedor. Una vez que haces el `[self removeFromSuperview]`(dentro de la secondView) la referencia `self.secondView` en el view controller contenedor ya deberia ser `nil`

Si deseas continuar por el camino que planteaste, no te queda otra que liberar la referencia de `self.secondView` a mano asignandola a nil.

Comment: Mi intención era mostrar otro ViewController a modo de ir a otra "pantalla" sin usar el NavigationController. Quería mostrar otra pantalla independiente, por eso no uso "addChildViewController". Cuando libero la referencia con 'nil' no me quedaba claro que la memoria reservada al inicializar el objeto con "alloc init" fuese liberada, pues únicamente con 'nil' libero la referencia a la memoria reservada. Por eso mi pregunta si debería hacer un "dealloc" Gracias por responder.

Comment: Cuando decis ir a otra pantalla, Porque no haces un Present del nuevo VC y cuando terminas con el haces un dismiss? Esa es la forma de navegar natural de iOS si no quieres hacer un push.
Ahora si lo que se quieres hacer es reemplazar la vista del VC actual normalmente lo que se hace es por ejemplo tener 2 xibs para un VC. y simplemente cambiar la `self.view` entre uno y otro. El concepto de presentar un VC dentro de otro, se ve raro si no es un childViewController.

Si no me parece que lo que buscas es que la secondView sea una `UIView` no un VC. 
Me cuesta entender lo que intentas lograr

Comment: Efectivamente la idea que tenia era navegar ( ir a otra vista ) gracias por aclararme que lo debería mejor hacer con un Present.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de varias pruebas al final lo he dejado igualando la segunda vista a "nil" cuando no la uso y volviendo a hacer un "alloc init" cuando quiero usarla de nuevo. No me queda muy claro, dejo un tiempo abierto el post a ver si hay alguien mas que pueda dar su punto de vista.